# aggregate values in R by rule

Tags: r, aggregate

I am doing regression analysis to data with too many categorical levels. I wonder how should I aggregate values for multiple categorical levels? For example let's have data with two columns A (categorical) and B (numeric):

```
A   B
1   1
1   0
2   3
2   0
3   1
3   2
4   6
4   0
```

Now I wanted to combine adjacent levels within categorical variable A. Aggregation function is summation. The result should look like this:

```
A     B
A1-2  4
A3-4  9
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You failed to mention what the rule actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R method:

```
aggregate(B ~ A, data=transform(dat, A=cut(A,c(0,2,4),labels=c("A1-2","A3-4")) ), FUN=sum)

#     A B
#1 A1-2 4
#2 A3-4 9
```

Comment: Yes, this works also and it is somewhat simpler. Also adjustable range is great, at least I understand how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), create a new grouping variable by using `%/%` based on the values in 'A'.  Then, grouped by 'A1', we get the `sum` of 'B' and also `paste` the `unique` elements in 'A' together.  If not needed, the grouping variable 'A1' can be assigned to NULL.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, A1:= (A-1)%/%2 +1][, 
  list(A= paste0("A",paste(unique(A), 
             collapse="-")), B= sum(B)) ,A1][,A1:= NULL][]
#      A B
#1: A1-2 4
#2: A3-4 9
```